# Can laravel create a view inside resources/views?

Tags: laravel

I have succesfully been able to create a file inside Storage / Public, but I am wondering if anyone knows if you can create a view inside resources/views with any laravel functions?

Comment: You _could_ but you shouldn't. Views are not meant to be changed at runtime.

Comment: Understood, it's for a page template system I am creating. Do you know how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no direct command to do this but you can use the package Artisan View. This package adds a couple of view-related commands to Artisan in your Laravel projects. You can try this : [Artisan View](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view)